# Use Google Play without any other Google apps installed

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, google-account

I'm using Cyanogen Mod 10.1 and I wonder if there is any possibility to use Google Play without installing all Google apps. I don't need Gmail, Talk, etc. I don't want to link my device to google. Is there any way to just put in your Google account data for Google Play and not for the whole device?

Comment: *I don't want to link my device to google* means you cannot use Google Play either, sorry. There are alternatives, of course − but not with a repository as big as Google Play.

Comment: @Izzy is correct, all of the google apps will automatically pair with your google account if you sync your google account with your device.

Comment: I found myself an answer: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1918484 Now only Google Play is installed without Gmail, Talk, ... but I had to link my phone anyway to Google.

Comment: It is possible to install just the play store without the rest of the Gapps stuff.  See [Minimal set of .apk files to enable Google Play](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33806/23562).

Comment: @Compro01 sure it is. But that doesn't change a thing concerning the device being "linked", which the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @Izzy - To me, the question is unclear about what is actually wanted.  The title and last sentence suggests he simply wants "only play, not gmail, hangouts, and stuff".

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214984/10015 is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that Google Play is not reliant on the other apps like Maps, Talk or Hangout. Just to be safe though, here is what I would recommend:

- Create a full system backup of phone
- Delete any apps that you don't want and see if they affect your usage
- If any apps affected your usage, restore your device and do not delete those apps.

Remember that it is always better to make a backup and not need it, than to need a backup and not have one =)