# How to limit Google account access to selected apps?

Tags: applications, google-account

I have used Google Photos App on iOS and the google account there allows me to disable access to the other google services where I don't see my other accounts in all Google Apps like Youtube, Gmail, Drive etc. 
This can't be done as far as I know on an android device. Although I can turn the automatic sync off but the account is pretty much there on all apps. 
Is it possible in some way that I achieve the same behavior as in iOS. It's pretty strange that google apps are giving more options on iOS than on Android.

Comment: I don't use Google products but there are two non-root possible ways I can think of. Either restrict Google apps' (YouTube, Gmail, Drive) ability to read accounts by denying AppOps operation `GET_ACCOUNTS`. Or add Google account to a new Work Profile and use Google Photos in that profile.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it.

### Method 1 - Ugly

If your phone supports multiple sessions (I mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtN4U.jpg)), then disable GApps except Google Photos in the new user session.

### Method 2 - Better

Use [Parallel Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en_US) and just run the Google Photos A.P.K. in it
I'm not sure here but I think if you are a privileged user you can direct the sign in to a webview.
As suggested by @chx, [`Shelter`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.typeblog.shelter&hl=en_US) is good, I just tested it, makes clone for [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neZxI.gif) apps when I tried to do it for Google Photos.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use Meet for workplace meetings but I absolutely didn't want my workplace account to be all over my phone, my emails, calendar etc. So I have installed [Shelter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.typeblog.shelter&hl=en_US). It's a delight to use. The app itself looks simple, it has two tabs, Main and Shelter. Initially I had only very few apps in the Shelter: Contacts, Files, Google Play Store (and Moto Actions). I can see them in the launcher, they have a little briefcase overlay, here are three normal icons with two versions of the Play Store:

[image: launcher icons]

I launched the work Play Store, added my workplace Google Account as prompted, installed Meet, the screenhshot has Messages next to it to show the difference:

[image: more icons]

The apps outside of the Shelter do not see my workplace account. This is absolutely perfect. Here's how Shelter now looks:

[image: shelter]

Comment: Link is dead and I can't find this app anymore. Is it still a thing?

Comment: Yes. https://github.com/PeterCxy/Shelter